# Считывание из файла в динамический массив структур

Tags: c++, структуры, файловый-ввод-вывод

Сейчас пишу курсовую, по заданию которой мне нужно создать что-то типа базы данных результатов сессии студентов, а также её обработку. База данных основана на динамическом массиве структур. По заданию мне нужно обеспечить сохранение базы в файл, и дальнейшая работа с файлом. (например вывод на экран информации о студентах, предварительно считав её с файла). Вот у меня и возникла проблема с считыванием структуры с файла. Вот код всей программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

using namespace std;

int n = 0;

struct Marks
{
    string SubjectName;
    string TeacherSurname;
    unsigned int Mark;
};

struct ExamResult
{
    string F;
    string I;
    string O;
    int NumberGradeBook;
    string FacultyName;
    unsigned int Course;
    Marks Result[5];
};

void InputInfo(ExamResult result[], int b)
{
    string temp; //FileName;
    string Kavichki = "\"";
    /*cout << "Введите путь и имя файла базы данных: ";
    getline(cin, temp);
    getline(cin, FileName);
    string NewFileName = (Kavichki + FileName) + Kavichki;*/
    ofstream ExamDataBase("save.txt", ofstream::app);

    cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    for (int i = 0 + n; i < b + n; i++)
    {

        cout << "\nВведите Фамилию: ";
        getline(cin, result[i].F, '\n');
        ExamDataBase << result[i].F << endl;

        cout << "\nВведите Имя: ";
        getline(cin, result[i].I, '\n');
        ExamDataBase << result[i].I << endl;

        cout << "\nВведите Отчество: ";
        getline(cin, result[i].O, '\n');
        ExamDataBase << result[i].O << endl;

        check3:cout << "\nВведите Номер зачетки: ";

        while (!(cin >> result[i].NumberGradeBook))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
            cout << "\nНекорректное значение! Нужно ввести цифру!" << endl;
            cout << "Введите Номер зачетки: ";
        }
        if (result[i].NumberGradeBook < 1 )
        {
            cout << "\nНекорректное значение! Число не может быть отрицательным или равным нулю!";
            goto check3;
        }
        if (i != 0)
        {
            if (result[i].NumberGradeBook == result[i-1].NumberGradeBook)
            {
                cout << "Такой номер зачетки уже существует!" << endl;
                goto check3;
            }
        }
        ExamDataBase << result[i].NumberGradeBook << endl;

        cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
        cout << "\nВведите Наименование факультета: ";
        getline(cin, result[i].FacultyName, '\n');
        ExamDataBase << result[i].FacultyName << endl;

    check1:cout << "\nВведите Курс: ";
        while (!(cin >> result[i].Course))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
            cout << "\nНекорректное значение! Нужно ввести цифру!" << endl;
            cout << "Введите Курс: ";
        }
        if (result[i].Course > 5 || result[i].Course == 0)
        {
            cout << "\nЗначение должно быть в диапазоне от 1 до 5";
            goto check1;
        }

        ExamDataBase << result[i].Course << endl;

        cout << "\nВведите результаты сессии по 5 предметам: " << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
            cout << "Введите Название предмета: ";
            getline(cin, result[i].Result[j].SubjectName, '\n');


            cout << "\nВведите Фамилию преподавателя: ";
            getline(cin, result[i].Result[j].TeacherSurname, '\n');


        check2:cout << "\nВведите Оценку: ";
            while (!(cin >> result[i].Result[j].Mark))
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
                cout << "\nНекорректное значение! Нужно ввести цифру!" << endl;
                cout << "Введите Oценку: ";
            }
            if (result[i].Result[j].Mark > 5 || result[i].Result[j].Mark == 0)
            {
                cout << "\nЗначение должно быть в диапазоне от 1 до 5";
                goto check2;
            }
            ExamDataBase << result[i].Result[j].SubjectName << endl;
            ExamDataBase << result[i].Result[j].TeacherSurname << endl;
            ExamDataBase << result[i].Result[j].Mark << endl;
        }
        cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    }
    ExamDataBase.close();
    n += b;
}

void OutputInfo(ExamResult result[])
{
    cout << endl << "Информация о результатах экзаменационной сессии студентов курса: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nФИО: " << result[i].F << " " << result[i].I[0] << "." << result[i].O[0] << "." << endl;
        cout << "Номер зачетки: " << result[i].NumberGradeBook << endl;
        cout << "Название Факультета: " << result[i].FacultyName << endl;
        cout << "Курс: " << result[i].Course << endl;
        cout << "\nРезультаты сессии: " << endl << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            cout << "Название предмета: " << result[i].Result[j].SubjectName << endl;
            cout << "Фамилия преподавателя: " << result[i].Result[j].TeacherSurname << endl;
            cout << "Оценка: " << result[i].Result[j].Mark << endl;
        }
    }
}

void ReadFromFile(int N)
{
    ExamResult* mas2 = new ExamResult[N];
    string temp;
    /*string FileName;
    string Kavichki = "\"";
    cout << "Введите путь и имя файла базы данных: ";
    getline(cin, temp);
    getline(cin, FileName);
    string NewFileName = (Kavichki + FileName) + Kavichki;*/
    ifstream ReadExamDataBase("save.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].F);
        getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].I);
        getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].O);
        ReadExamDataBase >> mas2[i].NumberGradeBook;
        getline(ReadExamDataBase, temp);
        getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].FacultyName);
        ReadExamDataBase >> mas2[i].Course;
        //cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].Result[j].SubjectName);
            getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].Result[j].TeacherSurname);
            getline(ReadExamDataBase, temp);
            ReadExamDataBase >> mas2[i].Result[j].Mark;
        }
    }
    ReadExamDataBase.close();
    OutputInfo(mas2);
    //ReadExamDataBase.close();
}


int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    const int N = 50;
    ExamResult* mas = new ExamResult[N];
    int function, position;
    int b = 2;

    cout << "Ввод исходных данных о студентах" << endl;
    cout << "Введите количество записей, которые вы хотите ввести: ";
    while (!(cin >> number))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
        cout << "\nНекорректное значение! Нужно ввести цифру!" << endl;
        cout << "Введите количество записей, которые вы хотите ввести: ";
    }
    InputInfo(mas, number);
    b++;

    number = 0;
    do
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Введите нужную функцию:" << endl;
        cout << "1 - Добавление нового студента" << endl;
        cout << "2 - Вывод на экран массива студентов" << endl;
        cout << "0 - Выход" << endl;
        cout << "Введите номер функции: ";
        cin >> function;
        switch (function)
        {
        case 1:cout << "Введите количество записей, которые вы хотите ввести: ";
            while (!(cin >> number))
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
                cout << "\nНекорректное значение! Нужно ввести цифру!" << endl;
                cout << "Введите количество записей, которые вы хотите ввести: ";
            }
            InputInfo(mas, number); b++; break;
        case 2: ReadFromFile(n);
            /*OutputInfo(mas);*/ break;
        case 0:break;
        default:cout << endl << "Такой функции нет" << endl;
        }

    } while (function != 0);
}
```

Собственно моя функция считывания с файла

```
void ReadFromFile(int N)
{
    ExamResult* mas2 = new ExamResult[N];
    string temp;
    ifstream ReadExamDataBase("save.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].F);
        getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].I);
        getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].O);
        ReadExamDataBase >> mas2[i].NumberGradeBook;
        getline(ReadExamDataBase, temp);
        getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].FacultyName);
        ReadExamDataBase >> mas2[i].Course;
        //cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].Result[j].SubjectName);
            getline(ReadExamDataBase, mas2[i].Result[j].TeacherSurname);
            getline(ReadExamDataBase, temp);
            ReadExamDataBase >> mas2[i].Result[j].Mark;
        }
    }
    ReadExamDataBase.close();
    OutputInfo(mas2);
    //ReadExamDataBase.close();
}
```

Проблема в том, что потом при выводе информации на экран (функция OutputInfo) у меня выводится только информация о 1 студенте (и то поле Subject Name почему-то не выводится, хотя всё остальное показывает корректно). То есть когда срабатывает функция вывода информация о 1 студенте выводится, а у остальных просто выводится мусор. Возможно я как-то не правильно считываю. Прошу помощи или подсказки у опытных программистов. Конечно разбираться в чужом коде это дело не благодарное (прошу прощения, просто я уже не знаю что мне делать).

Содержимое файла с которого идет чтение, после записи туда данных.

```
Petrenko
Max
Aleksandrovich
1
IKS
2
Matematika
Pribilov
2
Fizika
Ivanov
4
History
Nikylin
3
English
Mardarenko
5
Programmig
Filipov
3
```

Comment: А в файл записано правильно?

Comment: 1) Передавать размер массива в функцию `OutputInfo` через глобальную переменную `n` совсем не комильфо, т.к. существенно повышает сложность отладки программы. Передавайте размер аргументом функции. 2) Если у вас проблема с функциями `ReadFromFile` и `OutputInfo`, то к чему вся эта простыня кода? Приведите минимальное кол-во функций для воспроизведения проблемы + _исходные данные_.

Comment: @MBo да в файле всё записано нормально (через endl ).

Comment: Т.е. глазами в файле видно, что строки присутствуют?

Comment: @MBo да в файле всё записано по порядку, и всё то что вводилось.

Comment: @wololo добавил содержимое файла

Comment: Судя по файлу, каждое число находится на отдельной строке. А в коде после считывания числа, вы сразу читаете строку `getline`'ом. Но после считывания числа в файле остаётся не считанным символ новой строки. Отсюда и проблема. После чтения числа, но перед чтением очередной строки, нужно как-нибудь считать символ новой строки, например, так: `ReadExamDataBase.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: @wololo Да, ваше решение помогло мне:)